# list comprehension in matrix multiplication in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, matrix-multiplication

I have found a code of Matrix Multiplication in Python 3.x but I am not able to understand how list comprehension is working in the below code.

```
# Program to multiply two matrices using list comprehension

# 3x3 matrix
X = [[12,7,3],
    [4 ,5,6],
    [7 ,8,9]]

# 3x4 matrix
Y = [[5,8,1,2],
    [6,7,3,0],
    [4,5,9,1]]

# result is 3x4
result = [[sum(a*b for a,b in zip(X_row,Y_col)) for Y_col in zip(*Y)] for X_row in X]

for r in result:
   print(r)
```

Comment: You first need to understand what the `zip` and star operator do. You can the analyze each piece of the expression starting inside and out. You can easily execute `zip(*Y)` to determine what you get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

@Santosh, it's probably easier to understand this `List Comprehension` from pure `loop` way, like this:

```py
# 3x3 matrix
X = [[12,7,3],
     [4,5,6],
     [7,8,9]]
# 3x4 matrix
Y = [[5,8,1,2],
    [6,7,3,0],
    [4,5,9,1]]
# result is 3x4
result = [[0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0]]

# iterate through rows of X
for r in range(len(X)):
   # iterate through columns of Y
   for c in range(len(Y[0])):
       # iterate through rows of Y
       for k in range(len(Y)):
           result[r][c] += X[r][k] * Y[k][c]
           
print(result)
```

Then you prob. can find the similarity with the List Comprehension version, with little reformatting:

```py
def matrix_mul(X, Y):
    zip_b = list(zip(*Y))
    return [[sum(a * b for a, b in zip(row_a, col_b))
                 for col_b in zip_b]
            for row_a in X]
```